# Change the image path in Moodle for a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, moodle

In my case i want to change the href image icons when the user comes to contact us page. But those images are loaded from header file and i want to change the image path when it comes to contact us page.

```
<div class="header_nav_buttons" style="width: 25%;">
  <div id="first_img" style="float: left;margin-right: 3px;">
<a href="cth/support.php"><img src="cth/theme/boxxie/pix/tech_support.png"/><a>
</div>

<div id="second_img">
  <a href="cth/contact.php">
  <img id="contact_blue_icon" src="cth/theme/boxxie/pix/contact_us.png"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And i tried this Jquery codes.

```
$('#contact_blue_icon').each(function(){
  //Change the src of each img
  $(this).attr('src','cth/theme/boxxie/pix/blue_contact.png');
 });
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that a paste error or is your link not enclosed correctly?

Comment: It was a paste error and fixed it.

Comment: Why are you specifically trying to do this in javascript - wouldn't it be better to edit the theme to show a different icon on that page? Or even better, why not use CSS background-image property to set the image (instead of an explicit 'img' tag), then you can use the path-XX-yy class in the body tag to override the icon for the contact us page (within your theme CSS).

Comment: I used Content: url property first and it it not working in firefox. That's why i try to do it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

'contact_blue_icon' is an Id. It is an unique element 
Try with full image path

```
$('#contact_blue_icon').attr('src','http://image_path');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `id` is unique, you need to use class instead for your images:

```
<img class="contact_blue_icon" src="cth/theme/boxxie/pix/contact_us.png"/></a>
```

So you need `class="contact_blue_icon"` not `id="contact_blue_icon"`

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Do you receive any error in the console?

Comment: Yes i include the jquery and console gives no error message.